# Should I learn ruby first or directly dive in with ruby on rails with the hope to get the basics automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Should I learn ruby first or directly dive in with ruby on rails with the hope to get the basics automatically? In the next 2 months I need to extend a project with ruby, my background is 7 years of PHP-development.

Comment: Ruby first: learning basics is quick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info

Comment: Can there be a right answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

To get comfy with ruby (and for fun) definitely read [why's (poignant) guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/). Then dive into rails and check out great videos on [Railscasts by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby first http://tryruby.org this is an interactive ruby learning tool.

Then Rails For Zombies or Railstutorial.org

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Ruby first.
Then it may turn you don't need Rails :)

During learning process you'll need to see how your code behaves on various Ruby versions.

You could of course use RVM or rbenv, however you can run your code directly in browser.

See [CIBox.org](http://cibox.org/) for that.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of CIBox.org. Please do not treat this as advertising :)